500 Internal Server Error: [no body] error in RestTemplate of Spring when posting a large document (>7 MB) with POST method
I am using RestTemplate class to post a document to an endpoint from a Liferay application. But I encounter with this error:
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error: [no body]

It works for the other documents which are smaller than 7 MB. Here is the relevant part:
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
       headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)));
headers.setBearerAuth(this.getAccessToken());

HttpEntity<String> body = CommunicationUtil.getHttpBody(headers, document);

ResponseEntity<String>responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(api.getApiClient().getBasePath() + "/myPostEndpoint", HttpMethod.POST,
                body, String.class);

return responseEntity.getStatusCode();

The error appears after the exchange() method. Is there any file upload limit? Because I could not find any.
I am making this call inside a Liferay application with Tomcat.
And the body is not empty. I can assure it. But the doc content is too big.
Here is the stack trace:
500 Internal Server Error: [no body]
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error: [no body]
        at org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpServerErrorException.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:171)
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)
        at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:780)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:672)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:581)

